# domain with www showing another website

Tags: iframe, dns

I'm having a weird problem, my domain is [aridod.com](http://aridod.com) which is working fine but if i add www before aridod.com I mean [www.aridod.com](http://www.aridod.com) that takes me to [domainnamesales.com](http://domainnamesales.com) which is completely weird. I don't know how it happens. My source files fairly simple html. I looked into the browser source i saw iframe is injected anyway. And it is not anyway happening from source files & here is my dns settings : [image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Change the www record in your DNS settings.  It's pointing to the wrong place.  If you made the change recently, it may be propagating.

Comment: @loganbertram can you please clear me a bit, i thought i put the right Ip address for www record & couldn't get what I change it to :/

Comment: DNS propagation may take up to 48 hrs (rarely).  Use https://www.whatsmydns.net/ to check what DNS servers around the world see for each relevant record.  You may have changed www correctly, and it may simply not be updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what you are doing, but if I run a few linux commands I see what I think is a glaring problem that many people encounter:

```
$ nslookup aridod.com
Address: 184.107.37.81
```

You seem to be including the name of the provider (not your site), see below:

```
$ nslookup 198.54.114.243 | grep name
243.114.54.198.in-addr.arpa name = premium37-1.web-hosting.com.
114.54.198.in-addr.arpa nameserver = nn101.namecheaphosting.com.
114.54.198.in-addr.arpa nameserver = nn1.namecheaphosting.com.
nn1.namecheaphosting.com    internet address = 199.188.205.137
```

This is not what you would want, I would think. You should be including the address site 184.107.37.81 not 198.54.114.243.

Comment: I've updated my records with 184.107.37.81 & let's see what happens. I'm sorry for my ignorance about this. thanks @Eamonn Kenny

Comment: No reason to apologize. Even experienced programmers like myself who don't look after website backends would make this mistake easily. This is why its always good to look into your domain records of the provider to get the correct information. Not everyone would use linux to easily arrive at the information that I sent to you.

Comment: thnks again @Eamonn

Comment: Yea, sorry I forgot that I should mark your answer as working, so here u go.. a lot of thanks @Eamonn

Comment: Do not use ANY type and always specify the nameserver you are querying, starting with the authoritative ones before testing the recursive ones.

Comment: You are right. Its now deprecated and I haven't used it for 10 years so didn't realise this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The `domainnamesales.com` and `www.aridod.com` point to the same Ip address in you DNS. So the browser misleading you.

You can check the DNS of the domians by `ping domainnamesales.com` and `ping www.aridod.com`. You may get same Ip address， You can check the file `/etc/hosts` first. There may be settings of `www.aridod.com`or `domainnamesales.com`, remove it

Comment: But I don't see anything for www.aridod.com or domainnamesales.com
here https://imgur.com/a/3tBm8